# Proof of uniqueness of a push-out

Tags: algebraic-topology, proof-explanation

I'm reading the note about push-outs, and there's this proposition:

[image]

[image]

What is that universal property of Z that the author's talking about? I have no idea what it is so the rest of the proof doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: Please replace the images by actual text so that your question can be found using the search and is accessible to people using screen readers etc.

Comment: Which category are you working in?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown the objects here are topological spaces.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given a diagram
$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
A @>{f}>> Y\\
@V{g}VV \\
X,
\end{CD}
$$
a push-out is an object $Z$ together with morphisms $F\colon X\to Z$ and $G\colon Y\to Z$ such that the diagram
$$
\begin{CD}
A @>{f}>> Y\\
@V{g}VV @VV{G}V\\
X @>{F}>> Z
\end{CD}
$$
commutes and the following *universal property* is satisfied:

> Given any other $Z'$ with morphisms $F'$ and $G'$ such that
>   $$
> \begin{CD}
> A @>{f}>> Y\\
> @V{g}VV @VV{G'}V\\
> X @>{F'}>> Z'
> \end{CD}
> $$
>   commutes, there is a unique morphism $\psi\colon Z\to Z'$ such that $F'=\psi\circ F$ and $G'=\psi\circ G$:
>
> [image: diagram of the universal property]

Comment: In the proof of the push-out's existence, the space $Z$ is chosen to be $Z = (X \sqcup Y)/ \sim $, where $\sim$ is the equivalence relation generated by $f(a) \sim g(a), a \in A$. But I notice that the universal property of the sum already specifies a map $F_1$ between $X\sqcup Y$ and $Z'$, such that if $F'$ and $G'$ are maps between $X$ and $Z'$, and $Y$ and $Z'$ respectively, then $F_1 \circ inc_X = G'$ and $F_1 \circ inc_Y = F'$. So in the definition of $Z$ why do we need that extra bit about $\sim$, but not just $X \sqcup Y$ and $F_1$, i.e. why doesn't the following diagram work?

Comment: https://imgur.com/ItNPIBx

Comment: The square with $X\sqcup Y$ obviously does not commute when $A$ is non-empty, since you need $G(f(a))=F(g(a))$ for all $a\in A$.

Comment: So, in general (i.e. without the condition that $f(a) \sim g(a)$), the statement $F_1(inc_Y(f(a))) = F_1(inc_X(g(a)))$ for $a \in A$ is not guaranteed to be true by the universal property of the sum?

Comment: No, the universal property of the sum (coproduct, disjoint union) $X\sqcup Y$ with the inclusions $\iota_X$ and $\iota_Y$ is just that for each pair of maps $F'\colon X\to Z'$, $G'\colon Y\to Z'$ there is a unique map $\alpha\colon X\sqcup Y\to Z'$ such that $F'=\alpha\circ \iota_X$ and $G'=\alpha\circ\iota_Y$. The universal property of $X\sqcup Y$ doesn't mention $A$ and the maps $f\colon A\to Y$ and $g\colon A\to X$ at all. — In fact, the $X\sqcup Y$ is the pushout if and only if $A=\varnothing$.